# Remove a word from file names on Linux

Tags: linux, file-management, mv

I accidentally ran `exiftool -all= *` on my Linux system in my Downloads folder (the command removes the EXIF metadata from all files in the current directory). Luckily, `exiftool` creates backup files by adding the extension `_original` (so `untitled.jpg` becomes `untitled.jpg_original`. How can I remove this suffix from the original files (which I've moved into a folder) so I can make the original files have their original file names?

Comment: Possibility: [`vidir`](https://superuser.com/a/1503039/432690).

Answer (score 1):

#### rename

Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory containing the files that have `_original` at the end of their names and run this command:

```
find . -type f -name '*_original' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/_original//'
```

To find files that have an `_original` suffix in their file names run the first part of the above command.

```
find . -type f -name '*_original'
```

`find` files in subdirectories too and `rename` renames files wherever they are located, so the files don't need to be moved somewhere else before they are renamed.

`rename 's/_original//'` deletes `_original` from the names of the files that `find` found by replacing `_original` with a zero-length empty string.

#### sed and mv

If the `rename` program in your Linux distro is different from the `rename` that was used to test this code (Larry Wall's "Perl rename", `rename` on Debian based, `prename` on Red Hat based distributions), you can use `mv` instead of `rename` to rename files.

```
find . -type f -name '*_original' | sed -e 'p;s/_original//' | xargs -n2 mv
```

`find . -type f -name '*_original'` finds all files that have an `_original` suffix and `sed -e 'p;s/_original//' | xargs -n2 mv` replaces `_original` with a zero-length empty string.

Comment: Warning: In general in *nix there are [many similar programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) and `rename` in one distro may be [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210290/108618) than `rename` in another distro.

Comment: The `rename` above appears to be Larry Wall's "Perl rename" (`rename` on Debian, `prename` on RedHat). A very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

If they all are in one level of directories, it can be as simple as this with bash:

```
$ for i in *.jpg_original; do mv -v "$i" "${i/.jpg_original/.jpg}"; done
renamed 'test.jpg_original' -> 'test.jpg'
$
```