# AWK - Create new subdir and move files into it based on file name

Tags: linux, bash

I have loads (around 6000!) mp3's which I'd like to just dump into sub directories, based on the name of the file. Currently they're all in a single subdir. (There are already some existing directories for some artists, I don't wish to touch the files in these however a duplicate overwriting an existing file is fine).

The simplest way I can see of doing this, is by creating a subdirectory based on the file name, as the files are all named artist.artist.album.track.mp3.

After some searching I've come up with:

`for x in ./*.mp3; do awk x="${x}" -F. '{split(x,a,"."); mkdir a[1]; mv x a[1]/}'; done`

However it tells me there's a syntax error and unterminated regexp:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: x=./Dizzee.Rascal.Radio.1.Live.Lounge.03.That.s.Not.My.Name.mp3
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: x=./Dizzee.Rascal.Radio.1.Live.Lounge.03.That.s.Not.My.Name.mp3
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: x=./Dizzee.Rascal.Ultimate.Streetdance.CD1.03.Flex.Dave.Spoon.Mix.mp3
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: x=./Dizzee.Rascal.Ultimate.Streetdance.CD1.03.Flex.Dave.Spoon.Mix.mp3
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unterminated regexp
```

I think this is because the file name isn't given within speech marks but I'm not 100% sure?

Can someone help - and bonus points if you can get it to print out the progress too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `awk`? OK, let's assume `awk`…

- `x="${x}"` before what you want to be a program need `-v` (i.e. `-v x="${x}"`), otherwise it's interpreted as a program. This is the reason you get syntax errors.
- Your actual program is not meant to be executed per line of input, but per `awk` invocation; so you need `BEGIN`.
- You probably did not mean `a[1]`; maybe `a[2]`.
- The unquoted `/` (i.e. unquoted in the context of `awk`, not the shell) is wrong.
- `mkdir` and `mv` are not actions in `awk`. I think they are interpreted as (empty) variables. There is `system` action, you may use it. But since you need to pass an arbitrary file/directory name, these problems arise:

  - proper quoting;
  - command injection vulnerability (a part of filename may be interpreted as a command).

---

I say forget about `awk` here. The below code assumes you want directories named from the first two dot-separated segments. Notes:

- a file named `foo.mp3` will trigger an error from `mkdir -p ./foo.mp3/`;
- it's quite easy to modify the code so it uses one, three or another *fixed* number of dot-separated segments.

```
for x in ./*.mp3; do

   # remove leading ./
   d="${x#./}"

   # first segment
   d1="${d%%.*}"

   # remainder
   d="${d#*.}"

   # second segment
   d2="${d%%.*}"

   #result
   d="./${d1}.${d2}/"

   mkdir -p "$d" && mv "$x" "$d"
done
```

---

In any case I advise to create a separate directory to work with:

```
cp -al my_music/ my_music_copy/
cd my_music_copy/
```

This uses hardlinks, so it's fast and takes almost no additional disk space. Process the directory structure inside `my_music_copy/`. If you mess up hard, you can always get rid of `my_music_copy/` and start over. Only after you're sure everything is in its place inside `my_music_copy/`, remove `my_music/` and rename `my_music_copy/` to `my_music/`.

---

If there is no *fixed* number of segments and some heuristics is required, try `vidir`; something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.mp3' | EDITOR=vi vidir -
```

Then you can use the "search and replace" feature of the chosen editor to reliably create desired directories (e.g. replace `./Dizzee.Rascal.` with `./Dizzee.Rascal/`; but `./Mozart.` with `./Mozart/` and `./W.A.Mozart.` with `./W.A.Mozart/` or maybe with `./Mozart/` as well). See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1225530/432690).

Advantages:

- If something goes wrong, just do not save the file. Abort and start over.
- You don't need to process all the files at once. Files (lines) you don't touch will not be moved. Process a small chunk so you're sure this part is right; save, exit the editor. Invoke the command again to process remaining files.
- You can copy data to yet another tool (e.g. a spreadsheet), process there, paste back, save and exit.

Comment: I was using Awk, because.... that's what was suggested when googling ;) - Yes, there's variable number of 'dots' per artist, but I'm not moving these files into directories to be specifically per artist, just so the program that then processes the mp3s can deal with not loading 6000 at once ;) - I don't care if all the artists starting "My." end up in the same directory.

Comment: Also this worked (the non awk way) so mega thanks :)